# How to Compare sublists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find the smallest number out of a list made up of sublists. 
The output for the program should go like this:

```
least([[2,4,3],[1,7,9,4]])
in [[2,4,3],[1,7,9,4]] the least number is 1 found in sublist [1,7,9,4]
```

So far I have code that finds the smallest number in a list and that prints out sublists but how do I combine them together, that's really my issue.

```
# finds smallest number in list
def test(list1):
    x = list1[0]
    for i in list1:
        if i < x:
            x = i
    print(x)

# prints out sublists
def test2(num):
    for x in num:
        for y in x:
            print (y, end = " ")
        print("")
```

Does the body of "test" go before or after the line

```
for y in x:
```

Comment: Format your code please

Comment: You will need to use **recursion or stack/queue**. Since the list may be nested, which means you need to search for the minimum item inside of item (could be another similar list), then compare the results for all items.

Comment: Also, are you always going to have one level of nesting? Or do you want to support n-dimensional lists?

Comment: @NeoX question is not clear in that regard

Comment: @MadPhysicist its a n-dimensional lists

Comment: Do you mean that each sublist may contain other sublists? And those sublists may contain other sublists, etc?

Comment: no, i only mean that the main list can contain n-dimensional sublists.

Comment: Ok. So we have a main list, and each item in that list is a sublist. Each of those sublists just contains numbers, and the lengths of the sublists may vary. Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has a [built-in `min` function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#min). But I guess it's a good learning exercise to write your own.

We can write a function to find the sublist containing the minimum element by creating a modified version of your `test` function.

The key idea is to find the minimum of each sublist, and when we find a new minimum we store the sublist that that minimum came from.

In the code below I've change the function name from `test` to `minimum` to make it more meaningful.

```
def minimum(list1):
    ''' Finds smallest item in list1 '''
    x = list1[0]
    for i in list1:
        if i < x:
            x = i
    return x

def least(list2d):
    minseq = list2d[0]
    x = minimum(minseq)
    for seq in list2d[1:]:
        i = minimum(seq)
        if i < x:
            x = i
            minseq = seq
    print('In {} the least number is {} found in sublist {}'.format(list2d, x, minseq))

# Test

data = [[2, 4, 3], [1, 7, 9, 4], [6, 7, 5]]
least(data)
```

**output**

```
In [[2, 4, 3], [1, 7, 9, 4], [6, 7, 5]] the least number is 1 found in sublist [1, 7, 9, 4]
```

---

However, we can write this in a more compact way by using the built-in `min` function to find the smallest sublist for us. The trick here is that we get `min` to call itself to find the the minimum item in each sublist, and then use those minima to decide which sublist is the minimal one.

```
def least(list2d):
    minseq = min(list2d, key=min)
    x = min(minseq)
    print('In {} the least number is {} found in sublist {}'.format(list2d, x, minseq))
```

This version is slightly inefficient since it computes the minimum of the sublist with the smallest item twice. To avoid that we can pass `min` a generator expression:

```
def least(list2d):
    x, minseq = min((min(seq), seq) for seq in list2d)
    print('In {} the least number is {} found in sublist {}'.format(list2d, x, minseq))
```

That generator expression creates tuples of each sublist and its minimum, those tuples are then passed to the outer `min` call in order to find the tuple containing the smallest minimum. If 2 or more tuples tie for the minimum then the tuples themselves are compared to decide on the winner.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that sub lists are only one level deep you can do this by maintaining a variable containing the least value seen, and another to keep track of the list that contained that value:

```
lists =  [[2, 4, 3], [1, 7, 9, 4]]

min_list = None
min_value = lists[0][0]    # initialse to the first item of the first list

for sublist in lists:
    min_ = min(sublist)
    if min_ < min_value:
        min_value = min_
        min_list = sublist

print("the least number is {} found in sublist {}".format(min_value, min_list))
```

Comment: Your initial assumption is not correct based on clarification from comments

Comment: @MadPhysicist The clarification has been clarified further. ;)

Comment: So it has. Bit of a nomenclature collision there

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple:

```
>>> lst = [[2, 4, 3], [1, 7, 9, 4]]
>>> min_value_in_lst = min(min(sublist) for sublist in lst)
1
```

If you want to know where that min value came from, just simply create a loop:

```
for sublist in lst:
    if min_value_in_lst in sublist:
        return sublist
```

The full function:

```
def least(lst):
    min_value_in_lst = min(min(sublist) for sublist in lst)
    that_sublist = None

    for sublist in lst:
        if min_value_in_lst in sublist:
            that_sublist = sublist
            break

    # print out the result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need pythonic way to deal, then try this simple code:-

```
a = [[2,4,3],[1,7,9,4]]
min(reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, a))

Output:-
1
```

Comment: That doesn't identify the sublist which contains the minimum item.